# Changing a single record field to be strict leads to worse performance

Tags: haskell

I have a program that uses `haskell-src-exts`, and to improve performance I decided to make some record fields strict.  This resulted in much worse performance.

Here's the complete module that I'm changing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, BangPatterns #-}
module Cortex.Hackage.HaskellSrcExts.Language.Haskell.Exts.SrcSpan(
    SrcSpan, srcSpan, srcSpanFilename, srcSpanStartLine,
    srcSpanStartColumn, srcSpanEndLine, srcSpanEndColumn,
    ) where

import Control.DeepSeq
import Data.Data

data SrcSpan = SrcSpanX
    { srcSpanFilename    :: String
    , srcSpanStartLine   :: Int
    , srcSpanStartColumn :: Int
    , srcSpanEndLine     :: Int
    , srcSpanEndColumn   :: Int
    }
  deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Typeable,Data)

srcSpan :: String -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> SrcSpan
srcSpan fn !sl !sc !el !ec = SrcSpanX fn sl sc el ec

instance NFData SrcSpan where
    rnf (SrcSpanX x1 x2 x3 x4 x5) = rnf x1
```

Note that the only way to construct a `SrcSpan` is by using the `srcSpan` function which is strict in all the `Int`s.

With this code my program (sorry, I can't share it) runs in 163s.

Now change a single line, e.g.,

```
    , srcSpanStartLine   :: !Int
```

I.e., the `srcSpanStartLine` field is now marked as strict.  My program now takes 198s to run.  So making that one field strict increases the running time by about 20%.

How is this possible?  The code for the `srcSpan` function should be the same regardless since it is already strict.  The code for the `srcSpanStartLine` selector should be a bit simpler since it no longer has to evaluate.

I've experimented with `-funbox-strict-fields` and `-funbox-small-strict-field` on and off.  It doesn't make any noticeable difference.  I'm using ghc 7.8.3.

Has anyone seen something similar?  Any bright ideas what might cause it?

Comment: Looking at the core from -ddump-simpl, there's a new wrapper $WSrcSpanX when the strictness is introduced, and I'm not sure if it's being universally inlined.

Comment: It ought to be inlined, since the only use of the constructor is in this module.  But even if it isn't, it seems like a very high penalty for a wrapper.

Comment: How about cutting down your program to something you can share?

Answer (score 15):

With some more investigation I can answer my own question.  The short answer is [uniplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate).

Slightly longer answer.  In one place I used uniplate to get the children of a `Pat` (haskell-src-exts type for patterns).  The call looked like `children p` and the type of this instance of `children` was `Pat SrcSpanInfo -> [Pat SrcSpanInfo]`.  So it's doing no recursion, just returning the immediate children of a node.

Uniplate uses two very different methods depending on if there are strict fields in the type your operating on.  Without strict fields it reasonable fast, with strict fields it switches to using `gfoldl` and is incredibly slow.  And even though my use of uniplate didn't directly involve a strict field, it slowed down.

Conclusion: Beware uniplate if you have a strict field anywhere in sight!

Comment: Curiously, was geniplate insufficient for your needs?  Wouldn't it have avoided the issue and provided better performance?

Comment: Geniplate doesn't have the `children` function.  I use Geniplate everywhere else.